# How to set AutoCompleteTextView with his first value from the arrayAdapter with inputType of none

Tags: java, android, android-studio, autocompletetextview

So I have this AutoCompleteTextView

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/actv_choices"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Choose"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:text="Handicapped "/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is how it looks visualy

[image]

I want to achieve that when the client starts the activity it will initialize the value of the AutoCompleteTextView to be one of the values of my list values that I set in the adapter
for example, I got these values
[image]

And I want that when the client opens the app it will set the value to be for example the second value like that by default
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the adapter for your autoComplete textView you can do this:

Your custom data list ex. `List<YourCustomModel> data`

```
actvChoices.setText(data.get(index));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answear, but I want it to switch it with the adapter, is that even possible? like when I work with spiner...

Comment: You asked how to set a default value from your prepared list in the spinner when a user opens your app.
Is this your concern? Or anything else?

Comment: nevermind, thank you for helping. You'll get the bounty :)